# How do I resolve Parsing error: Unexpected token using vuejs (Resurfaced by plus-minus code as a reference in stackoverflow)

Tags: jquery, parsing, vue.js, node-modules, eslint

I am trying to create multiple plus-minus buttons for my application using VueJS. I have used halfpastfour.am sample code from this link
[jQuery multiple plus/minus Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806194/jquery-multiple-plus-minus-counter) as sample code for my project.

```js
$('.counter-btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $btn = $(this);
  $('#output-' + $btn.data('index')).html(function(i, val) {
    val = val * 1 + $btn.data('inc');
    return (val <= 0 ? '' : '+') + val;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Above is the portion of the code which states there is parsing error: unexpected token under the `$('.counter-btn')`

Shown like this:

> Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>   error: Parsing error: Unexpected token

I tried to resolve by referring to this post 
[ESLint Parsing error: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001552/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token?rq=1). However I am unable to find any .eslintrc file in my project. Besides that, I appreciate if you can enlighten on why does these parsing errors tend to appear often. Thanks once again.

Comment: The code you've shown does not create that error, as you can see from the snippet I edited in to your question. To check where the error is coming from, double click it in the console. Also check the value from `$btn.data('index')` is valid for use in a jQuery selector

Comment: Are you trying to use this code inside a Vue template?

Comment: @Gander Yes, I am currently using the code in the vue. However, for the function code above, I am using it under the script column.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your reply, I did some searching and realized I didn't import  ' import jQuery from 'jquery'
global.jQuery = require('jquery')
var $ = global.jQuery
window.$ = $
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery' into main.js. However, I encountered a warning which didn't allow me to see the updates for that particular vue component. I am quite lost of what else did I miss out.